# View missing model information

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have a class that extends the IdentityRole class:

```
public class Subscription : IdentityRole
    {
        //parameterless construcor required by EF
        public Subscription() { }

        public Subscription(string roleName) : base(roleName)
        {
        }

        public string SubscriptionID { get; set; }
        public override string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Expiration { get; set; }
    }
```

That is used within my `AppUser` class that extends `IdenityUser`

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public Subscription UserSubscription { get; set; } = new Subscription();
    }
```

Within my controller, I use a method within the `Subscription` class set the `UserSubscription` properties, where `model.Subsubscription` is a string

```
//it's been verified that the user properties are correctly set here
user.UserSubscription.SetSubscription(user.UserSubscription, model.Subscription);
return RedirectToAction("IndexUser");
```

However, when I render the following View, the `user.UserSubscription.Name` property is null

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Accounts";
    Layout = "_AdminLayout";
}

@model IEnumerable<AppUser>

<div class="bg-primary panel-body"><h4>@ViewBag.Title</h4></div>

<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Subscription Type</th><th>Email</th></tr>
    @if (Model.Count() == 0)
    {
        <tr><td colspan="3" class="text-center">No User Accounts</td></tr>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (AppUser user in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@user.Id</td><td>@user.UserName</td><td>@user.UserSubscription.Name</td><td>@user.Email</td>
                <td>
                    <form asp-action="DeleteUser" asp-route-id="@user.Id" method="post">
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" asp-action="EditUser" asp-route-id="@user.Id">Edit</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>

<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="CreateUser">Create</a>
```

In the View, all the other properties are correctly displayed except for the `user.UserSubscription.Name`. Why is this data not transferring to the view? I have a feeling it may be due to the `AppUser` class's `UserSubscription` property but am unsure how to properly set this up

Edit: sharing the SetSubscription method

```
public void SetSubscription(Subscription subscription, string subType)
        {
            var subscriptionType = subType.ToLower();

            if (subscriptionType == "t0")
            {
                subscription.Name = "T0";
                subscription.Expiration = null;
            }
            else if (subscriptionType == "t1")
            {
                subscription.Name = "T1";
                subscription.Expiration = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            }
            else if (subscriptionType == "t2")
            {
                subscription.Name = "T2";
                subscription.Expiration = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            }
            else if (subscriptionType == "t3")
            {
                subscription.Name = "T3";
                subscription.Expiration = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            }
        }
```

Although it seems to be correct in the CreateUser action method before the redirect, the UserSubscription Name property is null when passed via `userManager.Users` in

```
public IActionResult IndexUser() => View(userManager.Users);
```

I was able to work around this issue by deleting the Subscription.cs class that extended `IdentityRole` and instead extended the `AppUser` class

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Substription { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Expiration { get; set; }
    }
```

I then used a similar method of SetSubscription() to set the AppUser properties and changed the view to display `@user.Subscription` and it worked. This had the side benefit of simplifying my controller code. My remaining question is: does extending the IdentityUser class rather than the IdentityRole class lock me out of certain functionality that I may need later?

Comment: Please show us the code for `SetSubscription`.

Comment: If I'm reading right, that's an Identity `Role` `Name`(?)

Comment: @EdSF yes, that is the role name. I've also tried creating a separate 'Type' property within the Subscription class but I get the same issue

Comment: How are you populating the IEnumerable<AppUser> in the controller ?

Comment: is the FK configured correctly? are you including the navigation property in your query?

Comment: @Niko I added an edit to show the action method that implements userManager.users to populate the IEnumerable. The data is set correctly in the CreateUser action method, but is then lost before being passed in the IndexUser method

Comment: @DevilSuichiro sorry, I don&amp;#39;t quite follow. Im not using a foreign key or even a linq query, just relying on the RoleManager class. Maybe that's where I'm screwing up.

Comment: I'm no expert of Identity, but where does the user, you are setting the substriction to comes from ? What I mean is, are you sure that the value is "reflected" to the userstore and to be accessed by the usermanager ?

Comment: @Niko I tried adding `result = await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);` to try and update the userstore but I get the same result